# Direct product spaces of angular momentum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, hilbert-space, group-theory, group-representations

Consider the direct product space of two angular momentum eigenfunctions:

$$|j_1, j_2; m_1, m_2⟩ = |j_1, m_1⟩|j_2, m_2⟩$$

for the simple case when

$$j_1 = j_2 = 1/2.$$

How can i construct the direct product space explicitly and make the connection with group representation theory?

Answer (score 1):

The direct product space is spanned by the 4 states $\vert{s_1m_1}\rangle\vert{s_2,m_2}\rangle$.  This Hilbert space carries a representations of $\frac{1}{2}\otimes\frac{1}{2}$, and group theory tells you this representation is reducible as $1\oplus 0$.

Moreover, group theory explicitly helps in constructing states which reduce this representation since the search for irreducible subspaces amounts to a search for highest weight states, i.e. states killed by the action of the (here unique) raising operator so that $J_+\vert{j,j}\rangle=0$.

Once you have the highest weight you can generate the rest of the irreducible piece by the action of $J_-$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.I have one more question: which are the invariant subspaces and why?

Comment: The invariant subspaces are generates by lowering from the highest weight state, and they are invariant by definition.  Thus the 3-dim subspace generated by lowering from the  highest weight $\vert 1/2,1/2\rangle\vert 1/2,1/2\rangle$ is invariant.